# Where can I find the source code of os.urandom()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-internals

I want to investigate and study the code of python 3.7's `os.urandom()` function.
I had a look at the respective standard library's `os.py`, but neither is it defined there, nor is it imported there.
I also tried to grep for the definition:

`/usr/lib/python3.7 $ grep -rFl "def urandom" 2> /dev/null`
But nothing.
I suspect that there is some magic happening regarding os.urandom().
Where can I find the function definition for study and cryptoanalysis?

Comment: Some background about the current implementation: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0524/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of names defined for the `os` module are handled by [`Modules/posixmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/posixmodule.c), both on POSIX systems and on Windows. Note that the source code is in *C*, not Python, because accessing system functions requires native code.

You can see this is the [`os.py` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69f64b67e43c65c2178c865fd1be80ed07f02d3c/Lib/os.py#L48-L89), which either imports `posix` or `nt` based on the current OS, where both those names are compiled from the above `posixmodule.c` file but are renamed to reflect the platform better and to indicate that the functionality differs between the two variants (the `nt` variant provides fewer functions).

See the [`os_urandom_impl()` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69f64b67e43c65c2178c865fd1be80ed07f02d3c/Modules/posixmodule.c#L11232-L11261) for the implementation details of `os.urandom()`. This delegates to an internal function, `_PyOS_URandom()`, which together with other helper functions needed early in Python's startup process, is defined in [`Python/bootstrap_hash.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/bootstrap_hash.c).

Comment: Thank you. I traced the cord back to https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L306 wich basically is was I was looking for (WIN32 does not concert me atm.).

Comment: @RichardNeumann: `dev_urandom()` is the last resort function to be called. If you are on a OS that supports the [`getrandom()` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) then that's preferred (Linux, Solaris), next [`getentropy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getentropy.3.html) will be used (OpenBSD), and only if those calls are not available will Python read from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I must have skipped that.