# Does os.urandom() always use win32_urandom on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, random, cpython

In the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092441/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-of-os-urandom), we see that `os.urandom()` calls the function `_PyOS_URandom()` from  [Python/bootstrap_hash.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Python/bootstrap_hash.c). In line 531 of this document, I found that this function calls the function `pyurandom` from line 479 of the same document. In the comments above this function, it says that this tries to use four functions in order of preference (line 442-445). The first one of these is the function CryptGenRandom() for Windows. Now my question is: when you are on Windows, does the function always use CryptGenRandom()? Or may it be that this function fails and it tries one of the other three functions? The definition of `pyurandom` starts as follows:

```
static int
pyurandom(void *buffer, Py_ssize_t size, int blocking, int raise)
{
#if defined(PY_GETRANDOM) || defined(PY_GETENTROPY)
    int res;
#endif

    if (size < 0) {
        if (raise) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError,
                         "negative argument not allowed");
        }
        return -1;
    }

    if (size == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

#ifdef MS_WINDOWS
    return win32_urandom((unsigned char *)buffer, size, raise);
```

Comment: No the code is pretty clear, on windows win32_urandom is called and no error checking is done. The function can probably not fail.

Comment: @Fredrik "no error checking is done" is a bit ambiguous.  `win32_urandom` does error checking, but `pyurandom` doesn't fall back to other methods if an error is returned.